# Flask pdfkit not finding css

Tags: python, css, flask, pdfkit

I'm trying to make a pdf from my new Flask app, using pdf kit. I am trying to load a css file from my static directory and it just doesn't seem to work.

I am relying on the basic assumption that a css linked inside the template won't be picked up (as stated in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg20ZFqF7BE)).

I tried multiple suggestions that came up in different questions here and none worked:
loading the file path with url_for, using url_for with _external=True, using a literal path...

I'm getting `No such file or directory: 'pdf.css'` error with all the solutions I tried yet.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, I'm pretty lost here.

Thank you!

My pdf making function:

```
@login_required
def answers_pdf(username):
    # only the owner can download his own pdf
    if username != current_user.username:
        abort(403)
    rendered = render_template('pdf_template.html', user=current_user)

    css = ['static/pdf.css']

    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(
        rendered,
        False,
        css=css
    )

    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=out.pdf'

    return response
```

```
My project tree:
├───questionary
│   ├───main
│   │   └───function in routes.py file here
│   ├───static
│   │   └───css here
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───pdf template here
|   run.py -- running the app as a module from here
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try importing css inside html?

something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/questionary/static/pdf.css"/>
```